# Неизвестный тэг <:string-array>

Tags: android, android-studio, строки

Последнее время начал получать такую ошибку при попытке Rebuild project:

`Error:(60, 5) error: unknown tag <:string-array>`.

Сначала возникала в одном `xml` файле со `String`, закомментил весь файл, теперь возникает в другом. Строчки `<:string-array>` ни в одном из файлов нет, `Gradle` вроде не менял.

Не могу понять в чем причина. Может кто сталкивался, подскажите?

Пробовал: Rebuild Project, Make Project, Clean Project, Invalidate cache & restart. Ничего не помогает.

UPD:
Возможно вызвано ошибкой:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

В "Настройках" пишет "Gradle location is incorrect". Хотя путь указан латиницей и другие модули в проекте запускаются без проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге помогло добавление в `gradle.properties` проекта строки

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Странно, что все остальные модули и до этого работали стабильно, а само решение мало связано с изначальной ошибкой.

Кроме того, как я понял из SO-en, Aapt2 - это плагин для Gradle 3.+. Однако не понял для чего он нужен и к чему может привести его отключение.Если вдруг, буду благодарен пояснениям в комментариях.

Comment: путь должен быть не только латиницией, но и полностью состоять из ASCII символов (а по факту только из латинских букв, цифр и символов .  _ , начинаться с буквы). Есть мнение, что в версии плагина 3.2.+ это пофиксили

Comment: @pavlofff, Вы правы. Хотя вопрос, конечно, изначально не об этом, но в рамках интереса может подскажете, почему ругается на такой путь? `H:\Use\Android\AndroidStudio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1`.