# Почему создается проект с ошибками

Tags: android, android-studio

Каждый раз при создании проекта появляется 2 ошибки: первая - что-то на счет Aapt2, а вторая - конфликт зависимостей с библиотекой support-annotations. Обе эти ошибки легко решаются, но почему они вообще появляются в пустом проекте? почему Android Studio не выдает мне пустой проект, полностью готовый к работе? как мне это исправить?

Comment: Посмотрите, у меня тут такая же проблема с аапт2 была, решил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839995/Неизвестный-тэг-string-array

Comment: @Jarvis_J, да нет, решить ее не сложно, просто надоело каждый раз при создании проекта прописывать эту строку

Comment: да, мой вопрос "почему" тоже остался без ответа :( может вам повезет больше)